# How to set the Path of the Database for a Stimulsoft Report from the Code in C#?

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

I am working with a Stimulsoft Report in my application and i want to the change the  path of the Database as Current Directory how to pass the Path to the Report so that it can Change the Path as my wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ((StiSqlDatabase)report.Dictionary.Databases[ "Connection"]).ConnectionString = "(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source
                 =xxx;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;");"
```

Comment: An explanation, what a code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.